# Error al hacer Routing en Node Js

Tags: bootstrap, nodejs, navigation

Hola estoy aprendiendo **Node** y estoy utilizando la librería de **ejs** para hacer renders y routeos,pero tengo un problemita. Quisiera saber como puedo hacer para que mi navbar de **Bootstrap** apunte correctamente a mis rutas ...
Justo ahora así es como tengo mis respuestas del servidor y el navbar ...

```js
var express = require('express');
var engine = require('ejs-locals');

var app = express();
//var path    = require("path");
var serv = require('http').Server(app);
const port = 3000;


app.engine('ejs', engine);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');


app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  // res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/views/home/index.html'));
  res.render('home/index');
  //__dirname : It will resolve to your project folder.
});

app.get('/about', function(req, res) {
  // res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/views/home/index.html'));
  res.render('about/index');
  //__dirname : It will resolve to your project folder.
});

app.get('/chat', function(req, res) {
  res.render('chat/index');
});


serv.listen(port);
console.log('Server Started. ___ in port:' + port);
```

```html
<!-- Navegador implementado en vistas -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="home/">Project name</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about/">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="chat/">Chat</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="../navbar/">Default</a></li>
        <li><a href="../navbar-static-top/">Static top</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="./">Fixed top <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
```

cuando estoy en la raíz no hay problema puedo accesar a cualquier sitio **/home** , **/about**. El problema es cuando estoy dentro de una vista, supongamos que en "about/" cuando le doy click al anchor que apunta a "/home" me tira una petición con algo como esto ...
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En lugar de `about/`  , `/about`  y así con las demás rutas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al crear un enlace con la siguiente estructura

```
<li><a href="chat/">Chat</a></li>
```

Se está redirigiendo a la ruta `chat` pero lo hará **después** de la ruta actual, es decir si se encuentra en `misitio.dev/home`  , lo redirigirá a `misitio.dev/home/chat` y solo pensará que funciona cuando está en la  raíz de su sitio Web .

Sus enlaces deberían iniciar con `/` ya que con esto la ruta iniciará  siempre desde su directorio o sitio principal de proyecto.

Al crear el siguiente enlace

```
<li><a href="/chat">Chat</a></li>
```

Lo que estará redirigiendo es primero a la ruta principal de su sitio `/` y luego a `chat` , es decir si está actualmente en `misitio.dev/home/` y  luego selecciona la ruta `chat` , lo que pasará es que será redirigido a `misitio.dev/chat`  ya que `misitio.dev` es la ruta principal o Raíz de su sitio.

> [Para más detalle URL absolutas vs relativas en SOEn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005079/absolute-vs-relative-urls)

Comment: gracias wise man, todo trabajando súper :3